# selecting all elements with a certain tag in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 15 `UIButtons` with the same tag

How would I go about selecting/accessing all of them?

Ultimately, I want to change the properties of all of them on an event trigger, and I don't want to create 15 different IBOutlets, put them in an array.. etc.

Edit: I know I can access one element with

```
UIButton *btn= (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:12];
```

But how would I go by accessing more that have the same tag or other property

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in the standard API for doing this, but in the parent view, you could simply iterate over the subviews and check the tag property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write the if statement and loop through your subviews is like this:

```
for (id aSubview in self.view.subviews){
    if ([aSubview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] &&  ([(UIButton *)aSubview tag] == 42)) {
         NSLog(@"found button with tag 42");
         // do whatever here
     }
}
```

Comment: this seems correct cause 'id' can assume any kind of object but it still doesn't print.

If i do iterate through the view that it finds first, it seems to work tho:

for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)

for (UIButton *abc in btn.subviews)

if ([abc isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) .. nslog titleLabel text, it prints all the buttons' text. i was convinced yours would work, im not sure why it doesnt ?

Comment: @rdelmar, I think the problem is that the buttons are at multiple different nest levels within other views - I suggested the exact same code.

Comment: all the buttons are all within 1 view; there are no nestings. they are literally placed on a uiviewcontroller, no added views

Comment: i know what you're saying; that there's a nesting and i have to iterate through the view of a view. but that's not the case. 

also shouldn't  'for (id aSubview in self.view.subviews)' iterate through ALL subviews? that would make the nesting problem irrelevant, right ?

Comment: @PenguinSource, no, that won't iterate through all views, only the ones in the top level under self.view. If you have no other levels, then it should work.

Comment: @PenguinSource, your first comment seems to indicate that you do have a sub level. If you log self.view.subviews, do you just get one view or do you get all your buttons?

Comment: i get only one view ! and yes, it seems i do have one(extra) view, so that is my mistake, sorry; has a white background and i only made it cause i'm doing a popover and I want to see the borders. So this solves the issue. Cheers to both ! ..not sure how i missed that

Answer (score 3):

The `NSArray` option is easier. You can configure a single outlet like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection (UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

To use the tag you would need to write a recursive search algorithm (assuming the buttons could be in arbitrary container views).

Comment: i was not aware of iboutletCollection objects; i am trying to get Undo's soln to work, as it seems straightforward, too but this is just as good.

Comment: @PenguinSource You can upvote each answer you think is helpful for your problem.